# Find lines with a common value in a particular column

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Suppose I have a file like this

```
5  kata 45 buu
34 tuy  3  rre
21 ppo  90 ty
21 ret  60 buu
09 ret  89 ty
21 plk  1  uio
23 kata 90 ty
```

I want to have in output only the lines that contains repetead values on the 4th column. Therefore, my desired output would be this one:

```
5  kata 45 buu
21 ppo  90 ty
21 ret  60 buu
09 ret  89 ty
23 kata 90 ty
```

How can I perform this task?

I can identify and isolate the column of my interest with:

```
awk -F"," '{print $4}' file1 > file1_temp
```

and then check if there are repeated values and how many with:

```
awk '{dups[$1]++} END{for (num in dups) {print num,dups[num]}}' file1_temp
```

but that's not definitely what I would like to do..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to preserve the ordering would be to run through the file twice. The first time, keep a record of the counts, then print the ones with a count greater than 1 on the second pass:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { ++count[$4]; next } count[$4] > 1' file file
```

If you prefer not to loop through the file twice, you can keep track of things in a few arrays and do the printing in the `END` block:

```
 awk '{ line[NR] = $0; col[NR] = $4; ++count[$4] } 
  END { for (i = 1; i <= NR; ++i) if (count[col[i]] > 1) print line[i] }' file
```

Here `line` stores the contents of the whole line, `col` stores the fourth column and `count` does the same as before.